# Bootstrap datepicker disable feature years

Tags: datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to disable future years in bootstarp datepicker calender.
I tried following code,

```
 $('.dpd3').datepicker({
                format: " yyyy",
                viewMode: "years", 
                endDate: now(),           
                minViewMode: "years"
            });
```

Thanks

Comment: ...and what happened?

Comment: _"its not working"_ - is not particularly helpful. What the error?

Comment: future year not get disabled

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
$(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
        endDate: '+0d',
        autoclose: true
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tjnicolaides/cjp7y/

Comment: i want hide future years not  date

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function ()  {
    var nowDate = new Date();
    var today = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate() + 1, 0, 0, 0, 0) ;
    $('#Inputstartdatepkr').datetimepicker({
        language: 'en',
        pick12HourFormat: true,
        pickSeconds: false,
        startDate: today
    });
});
```

Comment: this will disable past dates on calendar control